# what does "conv_base.output" and "conv_base.input" mean or do in this code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

```
conv_base = Xception(include_top=False, input_tensor=None,
pooling=None, input_shape=(TARGET_SIZE, TARGET_SIZE, 3), classifier_activation='softmax')
                           
model = conv_base.output
model = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(model)
model = layers.Dense(5, activation = "softmax")(model)
model = models.Model(conv_base.input, model)

model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 0.001),
              loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics = ["acc"])
```

Can anyone please explain what  `conv_base.output`  and  `conv_base.input` mean in this code? What it is used for and what does it do??

Answer (score 0):

The [`tf.keras.models.Model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) needs `inputs` and `outputs` as arguments:

> Arguments:
> inputs: The input(s) of the model: a `keras.Input` object or list of
> `keras.Input` objects.
> outputs: The output(s) of the model. See Functional API example below.
> name: String, the name of the model.

In a Keras model, `model.input` and `model.output` return the input/output tensors, which you can pass as your new model's input/output:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19

base_model = VGG19(weights=None)

print(base_model.input)
```

```
Tensor("input_2:0", shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Note that calling these layers return a tensor, and not a model, so you seem to have mis-assigned your variable names. Rather, use something along the lines of:

```
model_output = conv_base.output
layer_output = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(model_output)
final_model_output = layers.Dense(5, activation = "softmax")(layer_output)
model = models.Model(conv_base.input, final_model_output)
```